# Python Memoization with dict - Performance Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, data-structures, memoization

I am using a genetic algorithm to solve an optimization problem.
I use memoization to speed up computation since fitness evaluation is time consuming. It is implemented in the following way:

```
def memoize(f):
    memo = {}
    def helper(my_input):
        if my_input not in memo:   
            if len(memo)%100000==0:
                print('increased memo size:', len(memo))

            memo[my_input] = f(my_input)
        return memo[my_input]
    return helper

@memoize
def eval_fitness(individual):
    #time consuming calc
    return fitness
```

I have noticed that the size of the memo dict increases quickly in the first generations and then increases more slowly (e.g. reaching 14M keys at generation 500). 
[image: memoization dictionary size]

On the other hand, the elapsed time for each generation is high (i.e. 40s) in the first generations and then decreases, as memoization pays off. 
[image: elapsed time per generation]
Nevertheless, as shown in the image above, i have noticed a non monotonic behavior of the elapsed time data series: the computation slows down and the overall computational time dramatically increases.

I use single process. Memory usage is safely under 20%.

- Any ideas about the underlying cause of this behaviour?
- How can I avoid this slow-down?

Answer (score 1):

That is probably **correct** behavior and you can't avoid it .

As your population changes randomly, there are moments when lots of new individuals occur. In these moments memorization do not grant strong time improvement(200->400 generations). On other hand if population stabilizes for few generations memorization works wonderful (around 200 and ~410).

> P.S
>
> Good decorator, but it is already implemented in functools module as lru_cache.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited my question adding the plot of the dictionary size at each generation. Actually, it indicates that there are not such moments of population stability / lots of new individual; indeed it is incoherent with the elapsed time plot.